Magento 2 : Print Invoice with Base Currency in Separate Line
In my magento, I have EUR as base currency and USD as additional currency. In backend, everything is working  fine, I see the orders with both currencies. However, when I print the invoice from backend, I see only the current currency (eg: USD if the customer placed the order in dollars). I'd like the printed invoice to also display both currencies. Getting the base amounts in base currency is not an issue. The issue is that the two amounts (dollar amount and base euro amount) are displayed next to each other, eg:
Grand Total $104.00 [€ 93.00]
Is it possible to have the base currency displayed under the currency just as it is in the backend? Something like this:
Grand Total $104.00 
           [€ 93.00]

